# How to load weights for specific subsubclassed model in Keras tensorflow

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, tensorflow2.0

The below code is just pseudo-code
I have this network architecture which is composed of multiple subclassed `Keras.models`. The basic layout of the entire network architecture is as follows:

```
    class Main(tf.keras.Model):
     def __init__(self, block):
        super(Main, self).__init__(dynamic=True)
        
        self.conv_1 = Conv2D(ncOut, kernel_size=(3,3), strides=(1,1),
                          padding="same", use_bias=False)
        self.conv_2 = Conv2D(ncOut, kernel_size=(3,3), strides=(1,1),
                          padding="same", use_bias=False) 
         self.block1 = block(...)
         self.block2 = block(next = block1)
         self.block3 = block(next = block2)

     def call(self, inputs):
            x = inputs[0]
            out = self.conv_1(x)
            self.block3(out)
            .
            .
            return out
```

```
    class Block(tf.keras.Model):
     def __init__(self, next):
        super(Block, self).__init__(dynamic=True)
        
        self.conv_1 = Conv2D(ncOut, kernel_size=(3,3), strides=(1,1),
                             padding="same", use_bias=False)
        self.conv_2 = Conv2D(ncOut, kernel_size=(3,3), strides=(1,1),
                             padding="same", use_bias=False') 
        self.next = next

     def call(self, inputs):
            x = inputs[0]
            out = self.conv_1(x)
            out = self.next(out)
            .
            .
            return out
```

This should get the gist of the architecture.
I.e, we have a subclassed model which creates entries other subclassed models that are then called.

After the network has trained, I save the weights. I then wish to make some changes to the network, i.e remove some layers or update the structure. Obviously, now it is no longer possible to load in the weights as there would be a mismatch.

What I then tried to do was give each layer a unique name (so during the creation of the blocks, I also pass a unique name). For the layers, like convolution and so forth, add a `name` argument with this unique name (plus an identifier for `conv_1` and so on), in hopes that I would be able to `load_weights(by_name=True)`.

Imagine that the structure is changed, I.e I removed `conv_2` from the Block structure. If I then went to load the weights it would complain that layer # block expected ____ weights but received ___. Even if `by_name=True` is enabled. This tells me that it tries to load the weights for the entire block, and not specifically for each layer in this block, i.e the named convolution.

How would I load the weights, `by the name`, for each of the layers in a subsubclassed model after the structure of the network has been changed?

I ended up doing it by recursion.

```
def recursion(input, i = 0):
    try:
        if input.layers and not input.layers[i:]:
            #we have exhausted the entire list
            return 

        if input.layers:
            recursion(input.layers[i], 0)

        recursion(input, i+1)
    except:
        #print(input.name)
        if input.name in layers_dict:
            print(input.name)
            #Take weights and set.
            weights = input.get_weights()
            layers_dict[input.name].set_weights(weights)
```

This seems to get the weights and set the weights for each layer as I wanted. For now, this works. If anyone has a better solution. Do not hesitate to suggest.

layers_dict is {"name_block_conv1": stripped_model.block.conv_1 ...}

Input: a model with weights

Comment: If I understand your question, is it - you trained a model A and get some weight And next you remove some layer and make a new model (like **old model - remove layer**) and wish to load the weight into this new model layer by layer?

Comment: Yes. Atm I am currently in the process of doing it by recursion, so we'll see. But if there's a better way with subsubclassed models, then don't hesitate to suggest @M.Innat